# Need to combine 3 formulas into 1

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Formula 1: List all items from `Estimate` tab

```excel
=QUERY(Estimate!A2:D50,"SELECT * where C is not null",0)
```

Formula 2: Locate task group matches within `taskItemAssociations`

```excel
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A9:A&B9:B&C9:C&D9:D, 
 TRIM(IFERROR(SPLIT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 {INDEX(QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(SORT(UNIQUE(IF((LEN('task-itemAssociations'!A2:A&'task-itemAssociations'!B2:B&'task-itemAssociations'!C2:C&'task-itemAssociations'!D2:D))*(LEN('task-itemAssociations'!E2:E)), 
 'task-itemAssociations'!A2:A&'task-itemAssociations'!B2:B&'task-itemAssociations'!C2:C&'task-itemAssociations'!D2:D&"♦"&'task-itemAssociations'!E2:E, )), 1, 1), "♦")), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0),,1), IF(
 ISNUMBER(QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(SORT(UNIQUE(IF((LEN('task-itemAssociations'!A2:A&'task-itemAssociations'!B2:B&'task-itemAssociations'!C2:C&'task-itemAssociations'!D2:D))*(LEN('task-itemAssociations'!E2:E)), 
 'task-itemAssociations'!A2:A&'task-itemAssociations'!B2:B&'task-itemAssociations'!C2:C&'task-itemAssociations'!D2:D&"♦"&'task-itemAssociations'!E2:E, )), 1, 1), "♦")), 
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0)),
 QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(SORT(UNIQUE(IF((LEN('task-itemAssociations'!A2:A&'task-itemAssociations'!B2:B&'task-itemAssociations'!C2:C&'task-itemAssociations'!D2:D))*(LEN('task-itemAssociations'!E2:E)), 
 'task-itemAssociations'!A2:A&'task-itemAssociations'!B2:B&'task-itemAssociations'!C2:C&'task-itemAssociations'!D2:D&"♦♥"&'task-itemAssociations'!E2:E, )), 1, 1), "♦")),
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2 limit 0", 0), )})
 ,,999^99))), "♥"))), {2}, 0)))
```

Formula 3: List all matches from `taskData` tab

This result is really all I need.  I'm just not sure how else to arrive here without all of the above.

```excel
=QUERY(taskData!C2:O,"SELECT * where C = '"&E9&"'",0)
```

[image]
Ideally, this would be a single `ARRAYFORMULA` in `Tasks!A2` (currently occupied by notes)

Here is [my sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Za3a9d3hKJCMAxy72sIRH9L61wLwvBw02Fwj_9E_z-4/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste in **A2** cell:

```
=FILTER(taskData!C2:O, REGEXMATCH(taskData!C2:C, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 
 ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(
 INDEX(QUERY(Estimate!A2:D50,"where C is not null",0),,1)&
 INDEX(QUERY(Estimate!A2:D50,"where C is not null",0),,2)&
 INDEX(QUERY(Estimate!A2:D50,"where C is not null",0),,3)&
 INDEX(QUERY(Estimate!A2:D50,"where C is not null",0),,4), 
 TRIM(IFERROR(SPLIT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 {INDEX(QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(SORT(UNIQUE(IF((LEN(
 'task-itemAssociations'!A2:A&'task-itemAssociations'!B2:B&'task-itemAssociations'!C2:C&
 'task-itemAssociations'!D2:D))*(LEN('task-itemAssociations'!E2:E)), 
 'task-itemAssociations'!A2:A&'task-itemAssociations'!B2:B&'task-itemAssociations'!C2:C&
 'task-itemAssociations'!D2:D&"♦"&'task-itemAssociations'!E2:E, )), 1, 1), "♦")), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0),,1), IF(
 ISNUMBER(QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(SORT(UNIQUE(IF((LEN(
 'task-itemAssociations'!A2:A&'task-itemAssociations'!B2:B&'task-itemAssociations'!C2:C&
 'task-itemAssociations'!D2:D))*(LEN('task-itemAssociations'!E2:E)), 
 'task-itemAssociations'!A2:A&'task-itemAssociations'!B2:B&'task-itemAssociations'!C2:C&
 'task-itemAssociations'!D2:D&"♦"&'task-itemAssociations'!E2:E, )), 1, 1), "♦")), 
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0)),
 QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(SORT(UNIQUE(IF((LEN(
 'task-itemAssociations'!A2:A&'task-itemAssociations'!B2:B&'task-itemAssociations'!C2:C&
 'task-itemAssociations'!D2:D))*(LEN('task-itemAssociations'!E2:E)), 
 'task-itemAssociations'!A2:A&'task-itemAssociations'!B2:B&'task-itemAssociations'!C2:C&
 'task-itemAssociations'!D2:D&"♦♥"&'task-itemAssociations'!E2:E, )), 1, 1), "♦")),
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2 limit 0", 0), )})
 ,,999^99))), "♥"))), {2}, 0))))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I didn't think about this until I saw the formula in action, but would it be possible to include `Estimate!E2:F` (Activity & Qty) to the corresponding task groups in `Tasks`?  It could be as simple as appending it to the first or last column, but I'll need those to multiply the times in `Tasks!F2:I`.  Thank you for everything!  You're amazing!

Comment: How can I add an additional column to the criteria? I tried adding 
`INDEX(QUERY('estimate-Tally'!A2:F,"where C is not null",0),,5), `, and fiddled with the rest of the formula, but not quite getting it...

Comment: first, you will need to explain it to me in more detail what you want where in which part, etc.because I have no idea what are you after :)

Comment: Yeah, I realized shortly after asking that I may need to do a little reformatting to make it work...

Comment: I have one "final request" for this formula: currently, if there is no selection/match, ALL possibilities are displayed.  Can it be adjusted to show nothing/blank instead?  I thought I could just enter a `""` after one of the `IFERROR`'s, but I don't think that will do the trick.

Comment: that may not but if you just wrap it all into IFERROR that may be sufficient